# My collection of OO class isnt working?

Tags: php, oop

Here are my three pages.

OOexamples.php:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once 'includes/'.$class_name . '.php';
}

$ObjColl = new ObjectCollection();
$bike1 = new Bike("R1", 1000);
$ObjColl->addItem($bike1);
$bike2 = new Bike("R6", 600);
$ObjColl->addItem($bike2);
$bike3 = new Bike("Bandit", 1000);
$ObjColl->addItem($bike3);
$bike4 = new Bike("Trial", 600);
$ObjColl->addItem($bike4);

for($i = 0;$ObjColl->getItemCount();$i++){
$item = $ObjColl->getItem($i);
if ($item instanceof Bike) {
 print "Bike - ";
}

print $item;
}
```

ObjectCollection.php:

```
 class ObjectCollection  
{  
//This is an array to hold line items
    private $items_array ;

    private $itemCounter; //Count the number of items

    public function __construct() {
        //Create an array object to hold line items
        $this->items_array = array();
        $this->itemCounter=0; 
     }

    public function getItemCount(){
        return $this->itemCounter;
    }  



    public function addItem($item) {
       $this->itemCounter++;
       $this->items_array[] = $item;
    }

    public function getItem() {
        return $this-> Bike = $item;
}
}
```

Im 80% sure it is something to do with the function "getItem" above. the line "return $this-> Bike = $item;" makes my page white and it never stops loading?

Bike.php:

```
class Bike {
    private $name;
    private $model;
    private $cc;

    public function __construct($name,$model){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function set_cc($cc) {
        $this->cc = $cc;

    }
    public function get_cc() {
        return $this->cc;
} 

}
```

Why is my for each loop not printing out the Bike objects? I know its something to do with the for each loop on the OOexamples page.? Please help its driving me crazy. Im a beginner on OO so go easy. The error im getting is "Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in includes/ObjectCollection.php on line 27"

Comment: `_contstruct` wrong for two reasons; 1) missing an underscore 2) typo

Comment: "not working" is essentially useless information. Tell us **HOW** it isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, ive edited the question

Comment: `public function _contstruct($name,$model){` still the same; I don't see an edit.

Comment: Done it. Its the foreach loop on the page OOexamples.php that is throwing me off, and the GetItem function on the ObjectiveCollection.php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 0;$ObjColl->getItemCount();$i++){
```

Should be:

```
for($i = 0;$i < $ObjColl->getItemCount();$i++){
```

Otherwise your loop will never quit, because there is no comparison.

There is another mistake:

```
public function getItem() {
    return $this-> Bike = $item;
}
```

Not sure what this will do, but `$this->Bike` doesn't exist, because the class `ObjectCollection` has no attribute `Bike`. So assuming you want the method getItem to return the item by the given index, it should be:

```
public function getItem($index) {
    return $this->items_array[$index];
}
```

**In conclusion, this is how your program should look:**

**OOExamples.php:**

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
  require_once 'includes/'.$class_name . '.php';
}

$ObjColl = new ObjectCollection();
$bike1 = new Bike("R1", 1000);
$ObjColl->addItem($bike1);
$bike2 = new Bike("R6", 600);
$ObjColl->addItem($bike2);
$bike3 = new Bike("Bandit", 1000);
$ObjColl->addItem($bike3);
$bike4 = new Bike("Trial", 600);
$ObjColl->addItem($bike4);

for($i = 0;$i < ObjColl->getItemCount();$i++){
  $item = $ObjColl->getItem($i);
  if ($item instanceof Bike) {
    print "Bike - ";
  }

  print $item->getName();
}
```

**ObjectCollection.php:**

```
class ObjectCollection  
{  
//This is an array to hold line items
  private $items_array ;

  private $itemCounter; //Count the number of items

  public function __construct() {
    //Create an array object to hold line items
    $this->items_array = array();
    $this->itemCounter=0; 
  }

  public function getItemCount(){
    return $this->itemCounter;
  }  

  public function addItem($item) {
     $this->itemCounter++;
     $this->items_array[] = $item;
  }

  public function getItem($index) {
    return $this->items_array[$index];
  }
}
```

**Bike.php:**

```
class Bike {
  private $name;
  private $model;
  private $cc;

  public function __construct($name,$model){
      $this->name = $name;
      $this->model = $model;
  }

  public function setCC($cc) {
      $this->cc = $cc;

  }

  public function getCC() {
    return $this->cc;
  } 

  public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = name;
  }

  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }

  public function setModel($model) {
    $this->model = model;
  }

  public function getModel() {
    return $this->model;
  }

}
```

Comment: You have lost me. Should the getItem() function be on the ObjectCollection.php page or the Bike.php page? From the OOexamples page, im trying to display the names of the bikes?

Comment: This is the error i got: "Bike - Catchable fatal error: Object of class Bike could not be converted to string in /OOexamples.php on line 30"

Comment: Its just displaying Bike- Bike- Bike- Bike-. Theres 4 bikes in the class so its recognising that. Its just not printing the name?

Comment: Are you sure your files are correct? I ran it on my local web server (with PHP) and it displays the names.

Comment: Yes it is displaying the names. Thanks for your help. Green ticked you :) !

Comment: Ofcourse, I forget `for($i = 0;$ObjColl->getItemCount();$i++){` must become `for($i = 0;$i < $ObjColl->getItemCount();$i++){` ...